# How to stop Rsys from sending log data

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rsyslog

Hello i am relatively new to rsyslog, and i have a file stored here /etc/rsyslog.d/ to tell rsyslog to send log data.

I now have enough data to analyze and would like to stop rsyslog from keep sending log data and waste my bandwidth.

So the question is how can i do this? Will removing the config file in /etc/rsyslog.d/ will simply stop rsyslog from sending the log file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply removing the file will not stop the logging.
you will have to issue a HUP to the PID of rsyslog.

```
kill -HUP <RSYSLOG PID>
```

This causes rsyslog to reread its configuration files in this case minus your config in /etc/rsyslog.d

Comment: Thanks, how do i know my Rsyslog PID ?

Comment: from the command line run the command 'ps -ef |grep rsyslog' this will return the entry regarding the running process. the PID is the 2nd field and will be a number.